# Was the Injeel ever written in book form?

Tags: prophet-isa, bible, revelation, scripture

Is there any evidence that Isa (a.s.) wrote the Injeel in book form? Because it seems that Allah has already gave him the Injeel when he was a baby.

> [Jesus] said, "Indeed, I am the servant of Allah . He has given me the Scripture and made me a prophet.
>
> Quran 19:30

Isa (a.s.) said this as a baby after his mother gave birth to him and took him to her people. So I was thinking that Allah put the revelations in his mind beforehand and the Injeel was never actually written.

This whole time the Injeel was just memorized inside Isa's mind. **If the Injeel was actually a written text, don't you think someone would have found it by now?** Instead, people keep finding very old un-canonical gospels written by Isa's disciples. No one ever finds the actual Injeel or what some people call "The Gospel of Jesus".

I could be wrong but I think the Injeel was in Isa's mind this whole time....not in actual text.

Answer (score 0):

There is neither a historical evidence nor a hint in the Quran that Jesus wrote down a book:

- No such book is ever menitoned in historical religios documents. It is not even related that Jesus has ever written down anything (except once in the sand).
- Suppose Jesus had written down something, why should those who fervently believed in him and even gave their lives for their faith have failed to relate it? Why should authors of the written Gospel not at least integrate it into their accounts?

The main underlying misunderstanding is that the Gospel writings *are* the Gospel. The right term to use for the written texts is to speak of *"Gospel accounts"*.

The Term Gospel, Greek: Euangelion, therefrom Arabic: Injil, means "Good Message". The Gospel is the *Message* God gave to the people through Jesus (p.b.u.h). This message was given by teachings and example deeds. Both, teachings and deeds are reported in the *Gospel accounts*, which were written down by scholars (John as an eye-witness, Mark in frist link in chain, as an author who had access to direct witnesses, Luke as a second link, Matthew and Thomas without known authors). They must be understood as hadith.

There are few more writings that may contain some truth but are too late to be reliable (e.g. the Infancy Gospel falsely attributed to James which shows some contents confirmed in the Quran), and a lot of earlier or later forgeries that intend to propagate teachings of the author as teachings of Jesus. The so-called Gospel of Barnabas is quite evidently a medieval forgery and - although the intention behind its writing is to adapt the accounts to Islamic teachings - it has no value.

The fact that the Injil is cited as a singular in the Quran may have two reasons:

- As mentioned above, the Euangelion is actually the message of God, which is not divided.
- The Syriac christian Tatian had made a compilation of the four canonical gospels in Aramaic in a single account which was still widely used in the Aramaic communities.

You write:

> This whole time the Injeel was just memorized inside Isa's mind. If the Injeel was actually a written text, don't you think someone would have found it by now? Instead, people keep finding very old un-canonical gospels written by Isa's disciples. No one ever finds the actual Injeel or what some people call "The Gospel of Jesus".

> I could be wrong but I think the Injeel was in Isa's mind this whole time....not in actual text.

I fully agree to this understanding. Any assumption of a "lost" Gospel written by Jesus (p.b.u.h) lacks any evidence, so that the "evidence" read from the Quran is just a misinterpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus never wrote any book he is the injeel to bring the good new ,himself being the messiah to save everyone. he choose the 12 disciples so he can fulfill the messianic prophecy , being eye witnesses , and learn from what Jesus has taught them so they can preach different nation(people) being gentile as well so he can be light for the gentile. (Mark 11:17,Mark 16:15,Luke 24:47,Matthew 24:14,Mark 13:10) and of course they need to write it they are eye witness of Jesus. or not we wouldn't accept it as truth. so he choose them. no were does the bible say "Jesus was reading the injeel" nor did it say "jesus was learning/writing the injeel" only says Jesus preached and the quran confirm this despite jesus having the injeel when mary took him to the people  as a baby Quran 19:30,  so no Jesus never wrote anything only preached

Answer (score -2):

According to the refrence of Gospel of st.bernabas and according to christians religious stories it waS well known that the mountain in the Nazrath called( jabley zaytoon) i.e mountain of Zaytuon was only the plACE where Jeuses Christ met the angel Gabrieal and he revealed him the holy gospel in ARamaic language (SOME TIME known as seriac language).and jesus reminded the whole revelation  this name is also mentioned clearly in the HOLY QURAN IN SURAH ALTEEN VERSE NO. 1 where ALLAH ALMIGHTY SWERE at the names of 3 holy places. then after that day the holy gospel i.e evengel was explored by the jeuses as he spoke beside his 12 apostels at diiferent occassions and at different places including all his life visited places as in jeudas ,in jerusalam and in kefer nahum and in galileth  and nazreth .during his sermons at  holy temlpe and among companey of his apostels he said that all the words which he speaks in his whole life before his lifting up to the heavens are the parts of the revelation which was given to him by the YEHWA the ALMIGHTY GOD.
the gist of the whole speech is that gospel of GOD was not actually written in the scriptual form i.e in book form .after his transfer from earth to the heavens .his apostels which were 12 in number ,narrated the whole life history of the jeuses christ in the book form .the main point is that every apostel of the jeuses christ wrote the life history of the jeuses christ as for example like gospel of judas , gospel of peter ,gospel of jhon ,gospel of methew , gospel of marry and many other like gospel of st bernabas .and  when  the apostels of jeuses were sett off on their preaching mission they preached about the miracles and good news and life events of jeuses christ whatever they had heard or seen in their life or whatever they wittnesed .and thatswhy  the people of that region had coppied their teachings and  their preached lectures and then gospels were spread all over the world  in the early christianity days but when st. paul took over the charge of christian religion he established his own faith rules and there is an importent point is that the gospels of christianty were became so common that every person claimed to be the writer of holy gospel thats why as a result the christians holy scriptuae i.e GOSPELS were reached to the counting of upto hundred books known as GOSPEL BY JEUSES CHRIST  then under the authority of romen empire all pops of the early christianity decided to pic up the any four canonical gospel out of those numerous fake gospels .they established a merit called (christians rule of faith ) and selected four gospels i.e of luke , methew mark and jhon. and all other were rejected .it is also claimed that in early christianty days the attacks of anti christ powers had severly harmed the rare scriptuas of their holy religion including hebrew context of the gospel of st. methew .thats why we can say that pure and rare holy gospel of jeuses was losted in the first century. christians leaders says that then after the REMOVAL of ALEXENDIAN CHURCH .THE ST.paul established the modern christianty .which is acceptable to the christian world even today.(published by ANEESI writers).

Comment: this is only the post which i have uploaded first tme in my life it doesnot relates or not pointingout some ones emotions it is only for the informative purpose for public only .it is finally based on my own life research about the HOLY GOSPEL@

Answer (score -4):

> Those who follow the Messenger, the unlettered prophet, whom they find written in what they have of the Torah and the Gospel, who enjoins upon them what is right and forbids them what is wrong and makes lawful for them the good things and prohibits for them the evil and relieves them of their burden and the shackles which were upon them. So they who have believed in him, honored him, supported him and followed the light which was sent down with him - it is those who will be the successful.
>
> Quran 7:157

In reference to the "Injeel" or "Gospel" that is being referenced by Muhammad, he believed it was available during the time when he existed. The problem that arises is that every piece of historical evidence we have points to the manuscripts that the Christian New Testament is translated from today. There is no historical evidence anywhere for there being a written gospel different than what is available in the New Testament today.

Comment: "Whatever Muhammad was talking about" - Could you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, in 7:157 it says "whom they find written in what they have of the Torah and the Gospel". Muhammad was talking about what was currently available that was written in the Torah and the Gospel. This injeel is what I was referring to when I said "Whatever Muhammad was talking about".

Comment: Are you answering from an Islamic point of view?

Comment: I am answering from a historians point of view.

Comment: We are not a typical an internet forum. Therefore we expect answers to be well elaborated, see "[how to answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)" for more information. I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about this site and the stack exchange model.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely take a look. The original question though was fairly simple. The short answer is yes, the Quran explicitly states that it was written and available. I thought I had already expanded beyond what was necessary, but I will review the guidelines.